# Pyspark - Convert values from two columns into dict

Tags: python, dictionary, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I've got this dataframe:

```
schema = [("clusterID", StringType(), True), \
  ("segment", StringType(), True)]

arr = [("cluster_comp_444", "Home equipment & interior design"), \
  ("cluster_comp_1160", "Going Out & shows"), \
  ("cluster_comp_217576624", "Healthcare & medicine"), \
  ("cluster_comp_465", "Good deals")]

df = spark.create_df(arr, schema)
```

I'd like to create a dict with this structure:

```
{"cluster_comp_444": "Home equipment & interior design", \
 "cluster_comp_1160": "Going Out & shows",
 "cluster_comp_217576624": "Healthcare & medicine",
 "cluster_comp_465": "Good deals"}
```

I tried this line but it's not what I need:

```
df.withColumn("json", fu.to_json(fu.struct("clusterID", "segment"))).show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use df.collect, which returns a row and use the 1st and 2nd element in a list comprehension to get the dict.

```
arr = [("cluster_comp_444", "Home equipment & interior design"), \
  ("cluster_comp_1160", "Going Out & shows"), \
  ("cluster_comp_217576624", "Healthcare & medicine"), \
  ("cluster_comp_465", "Good deals")]

df = spark.createDtaFrame(arr)    
dic = {row[0]:row[1] for row in df.collect()}
```